# Remove by date in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, files, find, timestamps

I have a shell script that creates a backup of a database. I would like to keep the last 7 days for files.

What is the syntax I need to remove files in a directory by date or can I keep the newest 7 files in a directory?

Script runs via cron

EDIT: something like this?

```
find -type f -mtime +7 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find /path/to/backups -type f -mtime +7 -maxdepth 1`, this will find all files older than 7 days which you could then delete.

Comment: Jan, see my edited question. Would that work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't work like that. Use `find /path/to/backups -type f -mtime +7 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -f {} \;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/backups -type f -mtime +7 -maxdepth 1 -delete
```

Your idea using `exec` could also be made to work, but you still need the path to the backup directory and your `exec` isn't quite right. It could be

```
find /path/to/backups -type f -mtime +7 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Also, I am not sure you need the `-maxdepth` option; are you worried about descending into child directories? I did not see anything about that in your question.